# Why does including <utility> break structured bindings in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, structured-bindings, gcc7

Consider:

```
struct Point { int x, y; };

int main()
{
    const auto [x, y] = Point{};
}
```

This code compiles fine with gcc 7.1 in C++17 mode, however this one:

```
#include <utility>

struct Point { int x, y; };

int main()
{
    const auto [x, y] = Point{};
}
```

gives an error:

```
bug.cpp: In function 'int main()':
bug.cpp:7:16: error: 'std::tuple_size<const Point>::value' is not an integral constant expression
     const auto [x, y] = Point{};
                ^~~~~~
```

What's going on here? A compiler bug, or is this how structured bindings are supposed to work?

Comment: I've just tested, and clang 4.0.0 behaves in the same way.

Comment: Looks like there were changes in this area at the recent Kona meeting (2017-02-27 - 2017-03-04). This feature isn't mature yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is compiler bug [78939](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78939). Although it's a bit more complicated than that - there were a few issues between the core language and the library that were mutually contradictory ([GB 20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0490r0.html), [LWG 2770](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2770), and [LWG 2446](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2446)), which lead to the kind of behavior that gcc/libstdc++ exhibit here. It is certainly *intended* that the code work with or without `#include <utility>`, it's just a matter of the standard wording having gotten there properly.

---

Yes, classes with all public non-anonymous union members should be usable in structured bindings declarations per [[dcl.struct.bind]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#4):

> Otherwise, all of `E`'s non-static data members shall be public direct members of `E` or of the same unambiguous public base class of `E`, `E` shall not have an anonymous union member, and the number of elements in the identifier-list shall be equal to the number of non-static data members of `E`. Designating the non-static data members of `E` as m0, m1, m2, ... (in declaration order), each vi is the name of an lvalue that refers to the member mi of e and whose type is cv Ti, where Ti is the declared type of that member; the referenced type is cv Ti. The lvalue is a bit-field if that member is a bit-field. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct S { int x1 : 2; volatile double y1; };
> S f();
> const auto [ x, y ] = f();
> ```

This is completely unrelated to the inclusion of `<utility>`, nothing in this code depends on any library functionality - the members are grabbed directly, and not via the `get`/`tuple_size` mechanism.

Comment: @MSalters Man, gcc bugzilla search sucks. I looked for a few minutes and couldn't find anything...

Comment: This is a standard bug caused by CWG and LWG not being in sync, not quite a compiler bug (it implements the specification to the letter). Originally step 2 of structured bindings checked `tuple_size<T>::value`, but `tuple_size<cv T>` wasn't SFINAE-friendly. So LWG changed `tuple_size<cv T>` to be empty if `tuple_size<T>::value` doesn't work. Then GB 20 says that checking `tuple_size<T>::value` is too user-hostile, so now core just checks if `tuple_size` is complete, and if so commits to the tuple-like mechanism. Of course that then wreaked havoc with library's fix to `tuple_size<cv T>`.

Comment: @T.C. Do you know, is there a plan to fix that? Is there a chance to get it fixed in C++17 or would we have a "hotfix" just after it is published?

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the edit. Odd that the old link still works, confused me for a while. Just an artifact? Wording itself looks the same to me.

Comment: @Barry Maybe they just copied the new files over without cleaning up the old ones when updating. IDK.

Answer (score 12):

The core idea behind structured bindings is that `std::tuple_size<T>` defines how many components you get from unpacking `T`, and `T::get<N>` should access the N'th element. Not surprising, this `std::tuple_size<T>` is a specialization from the base template in `<utility>`.

Now in this case, `Point` doesn't have such support for structured bindings, but it is a special case (all public non-static members) for which C++17 states that no special unpacking support is needed. This is an exception to the rule above.

The compiler is tripping over itself here, and trying to use the generic rule when it sees the unspecialized `std::tuple_size` from `<utility>`.